# New project for ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta not including unobstrusive validation Javascript files

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3

My problem today is rather simple, but its driving me nuts!

I just downloaded and installed the ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta and created a new project using VS 2010. But when I check the scripts folder, there are none of the following files there! (from what I understood, they should be there):

```
· /Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
· /Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
· /Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
· /Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
```

Anyone could tell me what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVC 3 templates should include those files. A couple of suggestions:

1. Are you sure you are using the MVC 3 project template (and not the MVC 2 project template)? I know it's obvious, but asking just in case.
2. Try shutting down Visual Studio and running `devenv.exe /InstallVsTemplates` from a Visual Studio command prompt. This command recreates VS's project template cache.

Let me know if these don't work.

Comment: These didn't work, but I discovered why... I installed the MVC 3 Preview, not the Beta. I saw that you work on microsoft @marcing, I found this http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes Release Notes that talk about MVC 3 Beta, but the download links points to the Preview. Thought you guys should fix that

Comment: @Kiranu Thanks for that report. Sometimes these details slip. We'll have that link fixed.